# Opening a Widget created in Designer, from a Main Window

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I’ve created 2 `.ui` files, one is a main window, the other a widget. Designer generates the 2 `.header` files each with `QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE` around the class declaration.

The problem is, what works in opening my main window, does not work in opening the second widget window.

To display my main window, I created a class that inherits from my `.ui` file:

```
  class myWindow: public QMainWindow, private Ui::uiClassWindow
  setupUi(this);
```

That opens fine, so then to open the second widget window, I declare a generic widget object and then save it with a pointer to my `Widget Ui` header file:

```
  QWidget newWidget;
  setupUi(newWidget)
```

But `setupUi` resolves to my Main Window header file… How do I tell it to use the Widget’s `setupUi`?

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Can you qualify the call by using the class name? That is, `OtherWidgetUI::setupUi(newWidget);`?

Answer (score 0):

Up to my knowledge, for setupUi function is defined in Ui namespace. You need to give scope (Ui) for other widget too.

Answer (score 0):

The `setupUi()` method is created by `uic` from your UI file, and it's different for each compiled UI.

In your `myWindow`, you inherit from `Ui::uiClassWindow` and can use its `setupUi()` method without qualification.  You'll need an instance of a different UI class for your `newWidget`:

```
auto widget_ui = new Ui::myWidget;
QWidget newWidget;
widget_ui->setupUi(newWidget)
```

You could `delete` the `widget_ui` immediately if you wanted - but usually, you'll need to keep it in order to access the children it has now created in `newWidget`.